# Selectively pulling commits for a build (via git & bamboo)

Tags: git, build, continuous-integration, bamboo

Is there any way I can selectively pick commits (or moreover groups of commits) and generate a build?

For example, let's say someone in my team has committed something and this is has been tested, but the piece I am working on has yet to be tested or is unfinished but has been committed. We would want the other changes to be 'pulled in' to go to prod, but my changes should be excluded.

We are using git, and use Atlassian Bamboo (we have JIRA integrated with issue numbers in commits, which also helps tracking multiple commits across a task).

Aside from maintaining different branches, or changing things from an operational perspective is there some easy way to achieve what I'm after?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's called branch-per-feature. When done correctly, you will always have a deployable release candidate branch and you will always be able to "roll back" a feature that went sour after deployment with out hacks like feature toggles. This is explained in detail here: http://dymitruk.com/blog/2012/02/05/branch-per-feature/

Comment: For others, I suggest also reading the blog that Adam's article was inspired by: http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/